# How to display Processing component in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I use a loading circle component when I want to read some data from RSS. I want to display this circle component to user for waiting.

here is my code:

```
private void btnUpdateRSS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtRSSGroup_Address.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                return;

            DialogResult dr = MsgBox.Show("اطلاعات قبلی از این RSS حذف شده و با اطلاعات جدید جایگزین می شود. \n \n آیا مطمئن به انجام عملیات به روز رسانی هستید؟", "هشدار", Mode.YesNo);

            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] RSSNews;

                    loadingCircleFF.Visible = true;
                    string address = txtRSSGroup_Address.Text.Trim();
                    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
                    {
                        RSSNews = Utility.RSSNews_Read(address);

                        for (int i = 0; i < RSSNews.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (RSSNews[i] != null && RSSNews[i] != string.Empty)
                            {
                                RSS.RSSGroup_ID = RSSGroupID;
                                RSS.RSS_Content = RSSNews[i];
                                RSS.RSS_PersianDate = FreeControls.PersianDate.Now.ToString("YYYY/MM/dd");
                                RSS.User_FirstName = GlobalVariable.User_FirstName;
                                RSS.User_LastName = GlobalVariable.User_LastName;

                                RSS.Insert();
                            }
                            else
                                break;
                        }

                        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { loadingCircleFF.Visible = false; }));
                    });

                    RSS.DeleteByGroup(RSSGroupID);

                    MsgBox.Show("عملیات به روز رسانی با موفقیت انجام شد.", "موفقیت", Mode.Information);
                    DTcancel_RSS(null, null);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MsgBox.Show("خطا در دریافت اطلاعات از RSS", "خطا", Mode.Information);
                }
            }

        }
```

but the problem is this:

before to display loading circle, it start to read from RSS and my application will be lock! so the loading circle never display.

how to fix this problem?

Comment: you have to start a new thread for RSSNews reading. And make display false only your RSSnews reading is completed.

Comment: Use Threading Concept

Comment: @kishoreVM how to know RSSnews reading is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your UI won't get a chance to repaint itself after you set `loadingCircleFF.Visible = true;`, after queuing a work item to the worker thread, your UI thread is busy handling `RSS.DeleteByGroup(RSSGroupID);` and `DTcancel_RSS(null, null);`, so it will not display immediately.

In my updated code, I placed them inside the body of QueueUserWorkItem, so they will not block your UI thread.

Noted that the work item is run on a worker thread so your app is not freezed. And when you hide loadingCircleFF after the RSSNews is successully read, you have to use BeginInvoke to marshal the call to the UI thread, since you can't access loadingCircleFF from a worker thread;

```
try
{
    string[] RSSNews;

    loadingCircleFF.Visible = true;
    string address = txtRSSGroup_Address.Text.Trim();
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
    {
        RSSNews = Utility.RSSNews_Read(address);

        for (int i = 0; i < RSSNews.Length; i++)
        {
            if (RSSNews[i] != null && RSSNews[i] != string.Empty)
            {
                RSS.RSSGroup_ID = RSSGroupID;
                RSS.RSS_Content = RSSNews[i];
                RSS.RSS_PersianDate = FreeControls.PersianDate.Now.ToString("YYYY/MM/dd");
                RSS.User_FirstName = GlobalVariable.User_FirstName;
                RSS.User_LastName = GlobalVariable.User_LastName;

                RSS.Insert();
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { 
            loadingCircleFF.Visible = false;
            //MessageBox.Show("عملیات به روز رسانی با موفقیت انجام شد.", "موفقیت");                            
            RSS.DeleteByGroup(RSSGroupID);

            //MessageBox.Show("عملیات به روز رسانی با موفقیت انجام شد.", "موفقیت");
            DTcancel_RSS(null, null);
        }));
        //If these methods don't access UI, call them normally, else wrap them with BeginInvoke.
        //RSS.DeleteByGroup(RSSGroupID);
        //DTcancel_RSS(null, null);
    });
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("خطا در دریافت اطلاعات از RSS", "خطا");
}
```

Comment: It didnt work. actually after reading the RSS, the circle loading will display

Comment: Can you show me all the code in your method, presumed it is a button's Click event handler? The circle loading will not display until all the code in your event handler has completed. Or you can call Application.DoEvents() to force a repaint.

Comment: How long does it take (in millisecons) to execute each of these lines `RSSNews = Utility.RSSNews_Read(address);`, `RSS.DeleteByGroup(RSSGroupID);` and `DTcancel_RSS(null, null);`?

Comment: Utility.RSSNews_Read(address) about 7000 msec, RSS.DeleteByGroup(RSSGroupID) about 1000 msec, and DTcancel_RSS(null, null) about  1000 msec

Comment: Thanks It worked. Can you explain your code shortly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60950/discussion-between-elahe-and-kennyzx).